# bootstrap toggle menu for mobile (only for mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a toggle menu for bootstrap only for mobile.

I have my header divided into three parts like below

```
   <div class = "col-xs-6">
       Test Test     Test Test
   Test Test
  </div>    

  <div class = "col-xs-2">
  Test Test
 </div> 

 <div class = "col-xs-4">
   <nav class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top visible-xs" role="navigation" id="">
  <div class="navbar-header" style="text-align:center;">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

So If you see the fiddle below, I am not able to get that toggle menu button for some reason.

http://jsfiddle.net/7KdD4/201/

Please help.

Comment: Works fine for me too.

You know you have `visible-xs` on the nav so if you are not testing in mobile view you won't be able to see the menu.

Comment: oops, wrong url of the fiddle

Comment: edited questions url also working fine

Comment: @Suraj It is because of `.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent; } `

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8i4OxKh.png

I can not see it here.

Comment: @Suraj Yes it is because of `background-color: transparent;`

Comment: Even after removing from the inspect element I am not able to get it.

Some silly illogical thing missing which I am unable to catch

Comment: @Suraj After removing here i can see that. http://i.stack.imgur.com/pS7ry.png

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HzctY.png